How does ionization of gas molecule affect the translational kinetic energy of the molecule?
Some things I understand to be true:

When we raise the temperature of a gas to around 10-20,000 Kelvin, the molecules of gas start to ionize, form a plasma, according to the Saha equation.
The temperature of a gas relates to the average kinetic energy, which for monotomic molecules, e.g. argon atoms, comprises the translational kinetic energy of the atoms of the gas (cf diatomic molecules, such as nitrogen, which can also hold rotational, and vibrational KE)

So... thinking this through... let's imagine a single atom of argon traveling along, at constant velocity $v$, and having kinetic energy $0.5mv^2$. Then, we suppose that its KE is high enough that it can ionize, and convert a large part of the KE into electrostatic PE. So ... the resulting ion and electron basically just stop moving? That would seem to violate laws of relativity, and mean we can extract energy from relative velocity? e.g. would allow us to convert the motion of the earth into usable energy? Since such things are generally not possible, I'm going to assume there are some flaws in my understanding of what happens during ionization of a monotomic gas atom/molecule?

Well, yes, it takes energy to ionize an atom. And that will lower the kinetic energy of the ion+electron (although note that many ionization events will occur in collisions so it is more complicated). This in no way violates relativity any more so than water evaporating below the boiling point.

If the atom is in a vacuum, then it cannot spontaneously ionise. Conservation of both energy and linear momentum are strict, and the combination of them implies that the simple linear motion must adhere with Newton's 1st Law. The ionisation that you are talking about can only happen when it collides with something, and then there are leeway for a redistribution of energy and momentum to allow these other possibilities to happen.

@naturallyInconsistent Ok, so you're saying that thermal ionization, when we raise the temperature of a gas to 20,000K or so, happens only when two molecules in that gas collide? That does seem plausible, and does appear to avoid the issues of violating conservation of energy and momentum etc.

Yes, in a sense, only due to collisions. It cannot be one single thing doing it.

That helps a lot. Thanks! Question: why do you say "in a sense"? That implies to me that there is some nuance/complication to the statement "only due to collisions"?

(also, @naturallyInconsistent, do you want to provide your answer as an answer? I feel like your answer is in fact the answer to my question?)

It is ok; I am not in a lack of reputation points. Also, your question deserves a slightly bigger answer that has some energy-momentum 4-vectors in them to illustrate. I leave that to someone else.

Wait. By symmetry, we have the same issue of conservation of momentum and energy when a free electron and an ion recombine? Does that mean that, in order to recombine, we need at least 3 particles to collide simultaneously? (the free electron, the ion, and one other particle?)

(that would also explain perhaps why we see appreciable ionization rate at very low temperatures, since 2 particles colliding is fairly likely - leading to ionization - but three particles colliding seems vanishingly unlikely?, so ions and free electrons tend to stay apart, once formed?

asked in a new question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/817402/how-can-a-free-electron-and-an-ion-in-a-plasma-recombine-without-violating-conse

@naturallyinconsistent provided the answer in his comments. I'm going to try to flesh that out here. But totally open to either @naturallyinconsistent, or someone else, providing a more complete/accurate/etc answer.
A single particle cannot spontaneously ionize. It's easy to see why not. Imagine that the particle is moving at velocity $v$, and thus has kinetic energy $mv^2$. But if we change our frame of reference to a frame that is also moving at $v$, now in our new frame, the particle has velocity $0$, and thus kinetic energy $0$.
The solution, that @naturallyinconsistent proposes, is that ionization can only happen when two things collide. In our case we are going to consider two atoms, but one of the things could presumably be a photon.
So, we can take eg two particles traveling towards each other with equal but opposite velocities. Their total momentum is zero. Their total kinetic energy is double that of each particle on its own. Changing our frame of reference can only increase the total kinetic energy, in our new frame, not reduce it to zero. Note that when two equal mass particles collide, we can always find a frame of reference moving such that the particles are moving towards each other with equal and opposite velocities, and with zero momentum, so this situation is very general.
When the particles collide, as long as the total kinetic energy, in our zero momentum frame of reference, is greater than the ionization energy, then one of the particles can ionize. Any excess kinetic energy, after taking off the ionization energy, will be conserved as kinetic energy of the particles after ionization.
This also solves the conundrum of why moving a jar of gas at high speed doesn't affect the temperature. Since ionization needs two particles moving at different velocities, so a gas where all particles are moving at high speed in the same direction, but with low relative velocities between the particles, cannot ionize.
Posting this answer so that 1. I can think through it, 2. there is an answer. All credit to @naturallyinconsistent though, so happy to remove it if/when he/she/they post an answer.
